# How does stringsAsFactors in data.frame() work?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
data <- sqlQuery(connection, "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1")

d <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

or

```
transform(d, col1 = as.character(col1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`d` in this cases still has `factor` type of columns.

```
str(d)

'd': 1943 obs. of 4 variables:
$ col1: Factor w/ 5 levels ....
```

But when I first state;

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

it works, but it sets it globally. Why do inside-statements has no effect?

Comment: `data` itself was a `data.frame` with the `col1` as `factor` i suppose. add separately the `col1` variable to `d` with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: What is `data`? Please consult the examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in order to improve your question. I'm pretty sure that while creating a reproducible example you will understand that this is highly unlikely that *stringsAsFactors in data.frame() does not work*

Comment: You should carefully read `?data.frame`. Every single argument is coerced to a `data.frame`. So, if any of the argument is already a `data.frame`, nothing changes. New character column are coerced according to `stringsAsFactors`. For the `transform` part, remember that it doesn't change function arguments *by reference*, so you should assign the result back: `d<-transform(d,col1=as.character(col1))` (note that the `stringsAsFactors` argument here is not necessary).

Comment: `data` is a query result from an ODBC channel. I don't know if it's the right way to find out but `typeof(data)` gives `"list"`

@DavidArenburg Thanks for the link. I'll read.

@nicola I forgot to assign the result of `transform()`. Rookie mistake :)

Comment: Very likely `data` is already a `data.frame`. Try `class(data)` or `is.data.frame(data)`. Remember that `data.frame`s are `list` objects.

Comment: A `data.frame` is a list. Why are you wrapping `data` into `data.frame`? You can just specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` within `sqlQuery` or use `as.is`. Try `data <- sqlQuery(connection, "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1", as.is = TRUE) ; str(data)`

Comment: It would have been helpful if you would have included the call `library(RODBC)` in your code snippet as `sqlQuery` is no function of base R -Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating the comment of David Ahrenburg, please try

```
data <- sqlQuery(connection, "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The help page `?sqlQuery` of package `RODBC` says:

> `sqlQuery` is the workhorse function of `RODBC`. It sends the SQL statement query to the server, [...] and retrieves (some or all of) the results via `sqlGetResults`.

`sqlQuery` has a `...` parameter for additional arguments to be passed to `sqlGetResults`.

Looking at the usage section of `sqlGetResults` (on the same help page) you will find that there is an argument `stringsAsFactors` which uses the following default:

> `stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors()`